# getting error while creating Web services with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting error while creating webservices on Ruby on Rails.

I have followed what ever the steps mentioned in [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ws-rubyrails/index.html).

After starting the Server with `rails server` command, when I am hitting `http://localhost:3000/hello_message/wsdl`, it's giving me the error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] /hello
>   message/wsdl)

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html 
end
```

Comment: Please provide enough sample code so we can at least understand what you did.

For this we need at least your routes.rb file.

Comment: below are the lines of code in routes.rb file
--
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file,seehttp://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end

Comment: which version rails you are using?

Comment: That article is from 2008 and was written to work with Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails <= 2.0. Both are very old and unmaintained versions. You simply cannot expect that the latest version of the `actionwebservice` gem that was released almost 10 years ago still works with an up-to-date Rails (5.1.x) and Ruby (2.4.x). Furthermore, I wonder why you want to implement a SOAP and XML-RPC web service in 2017 in Rails? Rails strongly advocates for restful JSON APIs for severals years already.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is from 2008, I'm not quite sure but maybe this could help you to fix it

Add `resources :hello_messages`
or 
`get '/hello_messages/wsdl' => 'hello_messages#hello_messages'`

This should be inside of `Rails.application.routes.draw do`

But I'll recommend you to look for more recent tutorials